# Sorting according to 2 different citeria with multiple list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have 2 list which is

```
list1 =[0.11,0.11,0.22,0.11,0.22]
list2 = [a,o,q,d,e]
```

I would like to sort them according to the number first then only alphabet.
my desire output:

```
list1 =[0.22,0.22,0.11,0.11,0.11] #sort decesding
list2 =[e,q,a,d,o] #sort acesding for first 2 since they have larger num in list 1, thn only sort others (acesding also)
```

I have try the following but it only sort according to one citeria

```
list1, list2 = zip(*sorted(zip(list1,list2), reverse=True))
```

please help........

Answer (score 1):

You'r close, try this.

```
list1, list2 = zip(*sorted(zip(list1,list2), key=lambda x : x[0], reverse=True))
```

---

```
list1

(0.22, 0.22, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11)

list2

('q', 'e', 'a', 'o', 'd')
```